# JSON access children in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following, simple JSON structure:

```
{
"a": {
    "value1": "w",
    "value2": "x"
},
"b": {
    "value1": "w",
    "value2": "x"
},
"c": {
    "value1": "w",
    "value2": "x"
}
```

}

...the desired output is as follows:

```
{
{
    "value1": "w",
    "value2": "x"
},
{
    "value1": "w",
    "value2": "x"
},
{
    "value1": "w",
    "value2": "x"
}
```

}

It would have to be plain Javascript (no jQuery). 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the result is a dictionary or a list? It looks like it should be a list.

Comment: ...the result would pretty much JSON without the parent nodes. Children content from the original version only.

Comment: Are you looking for the function `Object.values()`?

Comment: The wanted result is invalid JS.

Comment: yea Object.values() is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the keys and map the values.

```js
var object = { a: { value1: "w", value2: "x" }, b: { value1: "w", value2: "x" }, c: { value1: "w", value2: "x" } },
    array = Object.keys(object).map(function (key) { return object[key]; });

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With upcoming ES7 [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), you could use just the result.

```js
var object = { a: { value1: "w", value2: "x" }, b: { value1: "w", value2: "x" }, c: { value1: "w", value2: "x" } },
    array = Object.values(object);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @fafl, right, too much thinking ...

Comment: Thanks, this is enough :)